# Deleting an Azure Devops Test Case with c#

Tags: c#, rest, azure-devops

Azure Devops test case work items cannot be simply deleted online.  They need to be "permanently deleted".  And the code for deleting work items programatically does not work for test cases:

```
 workItemTrackingClient.DeleteWorkItemAsync(witID, true).SyncResult();
```

The MSFT documentation says to use their Rest API - but their documentation doesn't really explain how to do it - they simply show "delete" and a url.  I tried to use that url in a DELETE method rest call.  (I use Restsharp for its clear syntax usually), as follows:

```
            string adoURLBase = @"https://dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/";
            string urlToUse = adoURLBase +
               "ProjectName}/_apis/test/testcases/{workItemId}?api-version=7.0";
            RestClient client = new RestClient(urlToUse);
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest(adoURLBase, Method.Delete);
            request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + personalAccessToken);
            RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

This failed, with a StatusCode: NotFound, and the content message: "The provided HTTP Verb is not supported on this controller.".

FYI - I also tried using the full URL ("urlToUse" above) in the "new RestRequest" instantiation.  Same response.  And I tried adding trhe parameter "destroy=true" as noted in MSFT's documentation.  Same response.

The MSFT documentation I am looking at is at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `DeleteTestCaseAsync` method of [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/)

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TestManagement.TestPlanning.WebApi;

.............    

TestPlanHttpClient TestPlanClient = Connection.GetClient<TestPlanHttpClient>();
TestPlanClient.DeleteTestCaseAsync("YOUR_TEAM_PROJECT", TESTCASE_ID).Wait();
```

or use [Test Cases - Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/test-cases/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) REST API method